# C# Convert string to JSON errors

Tags: c#, html, json

Part of a public class I have builds a data structure for dataTables plugin.

The code to build the data structure is:

```
var response = "{ \"data\": [";
    response = response + "[";
    response = response + "\"Clark, Keith\",";
    response = response + "\"Corporate\",";
    response = response + "\"XXX-XXX-XXXX\",";
    response = response + "\"XXX-XXX-XXXX\",";
    response = response + "\"XXXX@XXXX.com\"";
    response = response + "],";
    response = response + "[";
    response = response + "\"Clark, Keith\",";
    response = response + "\"Corporate\",";
    response = response + "\"YYY-YYY-YYYY\",";
    response = response + "\"YYY-YYY-YYYY\",";
    response = response + "\"YYYY@XXXX.com\"";
    response = response + "]";
    response = response + "] }";

return response;
```

This runs fine and creates the table as expected.  Where I am running into issues is when I try to add HTML markup to a field.  I want to use a font awesome icon next to the name to indicate status like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-up" style="color: #00ff00;" aria-hidden="true">
```

I have tried modifying my code to read:

```
response = response + "\"<i class=\"\"fa fa-arrow-up\"\" style=\"\"color: #00ff00;\"\" aria-hidden=\"\"true\"\">Clark, Keith\",";
```

But now I am receiving an error that the JSON is not properly formatted.  Am I missing something or can HTML markup not be used inside a JSON structure?

Comment: You're not missing anything, html markup is not valid JSON. JSON strings must be totally self contained.

Comment: post the json with that new stuff in it. You're not trying to add it after the final close are you?

Comment: @JonathonChase there is nothing wrong with having html in it, html is just static text, which is exactly what JSON is good at.

Comment: Here's a tip, don't build json strings by hand.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado If not by hand, how would you suggest building it when it contains HTML markup that is conditional?

Comment: @Dispersia You're right, my mistake. I misread the intent and assumed the HTML was being built around the structure and not within it. The issue is most likely the double-quotes. They're escaped on the C# side, but not in the json string so it looks like incomplete properties.

Comment: @KeithClark .net has a library called JSON.Net, you just create an object and let the serializer handle the rest for you. it's literally plug and play. Also, in these scenarios try to use +=, it would be much easier to read

Comment: Instead of creating such JSON manually. You can write a corresponding class as per JSON structure and then create an object and assign the properties accordingly. Then you can use newtonsoft json to convert that object to json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're generating an invalid json string literal.

```
"<i class=""fa fa-arrow-up"" style=""color: #00ff00;"" aria-hidden=""true"">Clark, Keith",
```

Quotes are escaped using literal backslashes, not doubling them.

You would have had to do this instead:

```
"\"<i class=\\\"fa fa-arrow-up\\\" style=\\\"color: #00ff00;\\\" aria-hidden=\\\"true\\\">Clark, Keith\","
```

This demonstrates why exactly you shouldn't be generating strings like this.  There are tools out there that can do this for you and safely, use them.  Json.net will make easy work out of this.

```
var markup = "<i class=\"fa fa-arrow-up\" style=\"color: #00ff00;\" aria-hidden=\"true\">";
var response = new JObject
{
    ["data"] = new JArray
    {
        new JArray
        {
            markup + "Clark, Keith",
            "Corporate",
            "XXX-XXX-XXXX",
            "XXX-XXX-XXXX",
            "XXXX@XXXX.com",
        },
        new JArray
        {
            markup + "Clark, Keith",
            "Corporate",
            "YYY-YYY-YYYY",
            "YYY-YYY-YYYY",
            "YYYY@XXXX.com",
        },
    }
};
return response.ToString();
```

With that said, **you shouldn't be adding markup to your data**.  Data is data and nothing more.  If you want to affect how it is displayed, that markup should be added to your view.